# Add keyboard shortcuts to console application - mono compatible

Tags: c#, mono, keyboard, console

I'm looking at checking what keyboard buttons and combinations have been pressed while my console application is running.

One of the things I want to do is to trap Ctrl+C within the console app so that it doesn't just quit, instead does some tidying up and closes gracefully.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Console.CancelKeyPress` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx).

> This event is used in conjunction with
>   System.ConsoleCancelEventHandler and System.ConsoleCancelEventArgs.
>   The CancelKeyPress event enables a console application to intercept
>   the CTRL+C signal so the application can decide whether to continue
>   executing or terminate.

Comment: Thanks the control c was only an example, I also want to capture other keyboard events not just the ctrl c

Answer (score 1):

If your running under Unix/Linux use Mono.UnixSignal

I use this on my Linux apps. The advantage is that it will also detect a reboot or system shutdown.

This example comes from [this Mono FAQ page](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical#Operating_System_Questions)

```
// Catch SIGINT and SIGUSR1
UnixSignal[] signals = new UnixSignal [] {
    new UnixSignal (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGINT),
    new UnixSignal (Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGUSR1),
};

Thread signal_thread = new Thread (delegate () {
    while (true) {
        // Wait for a signal to be delivered
        int index = UnixSignal.WaitAny (signals, -1);

        Mono.Unix.Native.Signum signal = signals [index].Signum;

        // Notify the main thread that a signal was received,
    // you can use things like:
    //    Application.Invoke () for Gtk#
    //    Control.Invoke on Windows.Forms
    //    Write to a pipe created with UnixPipes for server apps.
    //    Use an AutoResetEvent

    // For example, this works with Gtk#    
    Application.Invoke (delegate () { ReceivedSignal (signal); }
    });
```